# How to plot a time series plot which one Y-variable and groups separated

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Festzelt': ["Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Hacker-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt", "Löwenbräu-Festzelt"],
    'Biermenge': [1.068510948, 1.111444388, 1.097928649, 1.097319892, 1.112046892, 1.096458863, 1.098193952, 1.105528912, 1.081012023, 1.096862587, 1.096820787, 1.112483864, 1.090409846, 1.076176749, 1.05914969, 1.111281072, 1.090280455, 1.071867235, 1.104982445, 1.074247709, 1.103154487, 1.136741808, 1.051554041, 1.089669195, 1.126347645, 1.105658808, 1.117330659, 1.101642591, 1.065208517, 1.082705561, 1.081997508, 1.100248942, 1.102306684, 1.106034801, 1.061078385, 1.065105824, 1.118714312, 1.103743509, 1.10806331, 1.127161842, 1.095313864, 1.083297614, 1.088053678, 1.096490414, 1.103947732, 1.070520785, 1.096987797, 1.045452588, 1.097941923, 1.087059407, 1.059211299, 1.004684239, 0.998865106, 1.011393955, 1.020030032, 1.000917207, 1.037486604, 1.058419981, 0.999914939, 1.037276828, 1.011935826, 1.00550927, 1.035434798, 1.049929295, 1.023505819, 1.04547058, 1.019198865, 1.01983709, 1.011544282, 1.019780386, 1.001639294, 1.027859424, 1.060448349, 1.047727746, 1.020635143, 1.030990766, 1.003855964, 1.024180945, 1.033970302, 1.024973412, 1.046135278, 1.031333533, 1.037277845, 1.023052959, 1.046540625, 1.014640256, 1.009600155, 0.988617146, 0.993939951, 1.019822804, 0.980809392, 1.034884526, 1.039759923, 1.019183791, 0.980610209, 1.015745219, 0.982644572, 1.019548832, 1.03694442, 0.984112046],
})
```

And need an output like this:

[image]

I have the following code which it is nearly what I want:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from charts.basechart import BaseChart
from charts.constants import FIGURE_SIZE_DEFAULT, TITLE_FONT_SIZE, COLORS, MARKERS, LINES


class Timeseriesplot2(BaseChart):
    def process(self):
        title = self.chart.config.title
        # Define data and parameters
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.chart.data)

        plt.figure(figsize=FIGURE_SIZE_DEFAULT)

        # Loop over pd an genrate plots
        for (index, column) in enumerate(df):
            y = df[column]
            x = range(1, df[column].count() + 1)
            count = df[column].count()

            plt.plot((x + (index * count)), y,
                     linestyle=LINES[index], marker=MARKERS[index], color=COLORS[index], label=df.columns[index])

        plt.legend(loc='best')

        plt.title(title, fontsize=TITLE_FONT_SIZE, pad=20)

        # Grid lines
        plt.grid()

        return plt
```

But I need the groups separated like in the image above. And the timeseries should start and end in the full range of the index in relation to the index of the position in the dataframe column.
I hope the explanation is clear.
Every help is aprreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the code to something like:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df['Festzelt'].unique()), sharey=True)

for i, (k, g) in enumerate(df.groupby('Festzelt')):
    g['Biermenge'].plot(ax=axes[i], marker='.')
    axes[i].set_title(k)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello mozway thank you for your fast answering. For me this looks perfect, clearer to look at like my example image. I'll try this out.
Greetings Jan